# Not able to get ID of button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get ID of a button using jquery,but not able to get it work.
Below is my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert(this.id); 
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="some_id1" type="button" value="0"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Below is the updated code but it still isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./gridster.js_files/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="some_id1" type="button" value="0"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**
This works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: There's no `$("button")` on the page.

Comment: Put the `script` tag before the closing `</body>` or use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting your handler on a `button` tag, but your html has an input tag. Change you selector for `$("input")`

```
$("input").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); 
});
```

Edit :

You could also keep the javascript and change your input for an html button :

```
<button id="some_id1" value="0">Click me!</button>
```

Edit 2, following OP's edit :

Your code is not working because it is executed before the button is written on your page. You have two choices : write the javascript after the body, or wrap your function like this :

```
$(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
       alert(this.id); 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSWam/)

Comment: You will also need to wrap any code that uses HTML elements inside of this: `$(function() { ... });` This will ensure that events are hooked up AFTER the elements are created.

Comment: Yes, either you write the javascript after the HTML, or you execute it when the page is ready like @Katana314 said.

Comment: @Downvoter I'm opened to critics, please explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ID of button, instead of simply writing button

[**Check this live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3c5M/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input").click(function( event ) {
        alert( this.id );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is more specific for your example:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

anyway you can do it with

```
$("input").click(function() {
        alert( this.id );
    });
```

as long as you have only 1 input in your html.